# Error uploading screenshots to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, screenshot

I am trying to upload an app to Google Play. So, I took some screenshots of my app, and tried to upload it. I took a PNG, then changed it to JPEG, and the I tried many, many, border pixels. But it always show error.

For example, I am trying to upload a JPEG file now, which is 640x360 pixels (its a JPEG, so there can be no alpha channel) and I am getting error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: it said "Error uploading", only that. See my answer to see what was happening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turned out to be an end of session trouble. I re-login at Google Play and everything was fine. but it didn't said it was a session problem. I will leave this here in case someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshots must follow these guidelines:

> - **JPEG or 24-bit PNG (no alpha)**
> - **Minimum dimension: 320 px**
> - **Maximum dimension: 3840 px**

I had similar problems with this, but once all those conditions were met - it worked fine.

Sources:
Google Developer Documentation:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en-GB